# References on the spectral theory of the Floquet problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, spectral-theory

The Floquet problem is about the linear ordinary differential equation

$$ \dot{\psi} = A(t) \psi. $$

Here $A(t)= A(t+T)$ is a periodic $n\times n $ matrix. Suppose $A(t) =-i H(t)$ with $H(t)$ being hermitian. Then, we have the one-period propagation unitary operator $ U (T) $, which is determined by the equation

$$ \dot{U} =  - i H(t) U(t),  $$

with $U(0) = I_{n\times n}$. Apparently, the spectrum of the operator $U(T)$ is very important.

Is there any good reference on it?

Comment: Are you asking about this particular example of periodic systems or about Floquet theory in general? As for Floquet theory I suggest to take a look at Meiss or Wiggins textbooks, for example.

Comment: You could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory